# The trouble with searching for a single-word sentence

Tags: search, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have a text field for tags. For example some entities:

```
{"tags": "apple. fruits. eat."}

{"tags": "green apple."}

{"tags": "banana. apple."}
```

I want to select entities with tag `apple`, not `green apple` or `smth apple smth`. Different variants lead to the one point: select a sentence with existing expression and it doesn't matter how this sentence looks like. But in this case it's matter.
How can I do it by using Lucene syntax or Azure Search tools? Or (in general) how can I search for a completely same sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the "." is a deliminator for the different tags.  There may be a way to express this in lucene, but you may need to add some custom analyzers to preserve the "."'s in tokenization.

A better strategy in this case would be use use a field of type Collection(Edm.String).  This will allow you to better preserve structure the phrases for the tags, and you can use a filter to select the specific value of "apple".  Collection(Edm.String) also allows you to enable faceting of the tags which is useful.